# HttpWebRequest via C# and UTF-8 charset

Tags: c#, character-encoding, httpwebrequest

I am trying to send a HttpWebRequest some data in Greek to my e-shop using c#. The problem is that in e-shop the greek chars. looks like `???????? ??????? 150?250`

My c# code is in bellow. If some knows how can fix this please help.

```
                EShopProduct eshopProduct = new EShopProduct();
                eshopProduct = GetEShopProductByProductCode(reference);

                string scode = eshopProduct.SCode;
                string name = eshopProduct.Name;
                string description = eshopProduct.Description;
                string quantity = eshopProduct.Quantity;
                string category = eshopCategoryId;
                string price = eshopProduct.Price;

                string postData = String.Format("scode={0}&name={1}&description={2}&quantity={3}&category={4}&price={5}&reference={6}",
                                                 scode, name, description, quantity, category, price, reference);

                string getUrl = _eshopUrl + "/insert_a_product_bysgs.php";

                HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
                getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
                getRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2"; // SGS Galaxy
                getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
                getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
                getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
                getRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

                byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
                getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
                Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
                newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
                newStream.Close();

                HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
                    new_product_id = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
```

Comment: You're encoding as ASCII, and not UTF8.

Comment: You're right man. Thank you. I see this just  post the question fix it and then you answered. Thank a lot! It works fine now!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
```

This encoding supports special characters such as Greek letters that are not included in the ASCII equivalent

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
```